# Create Record Type without discplay on the Select Recordd Type Page

Tags: workflow, page-layout, approval-process, record-type

I want to create two record types but don't want to display them on the select record type page.

Basically client requirement is to diplay the approval history Related list only if picklist value matches to the given criteria.

I am trying to do this by creating two different page layout and Recordtype. And than using workflow I am going to switch the record type as the picklist value.

However this record type are only for internal pupose and don't want to display on select record type page to confuse user.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't assign the Record Type to any user's Profiles, they won't see the new Record Type in the Select Record Type page picklist.

Here's the [Salesforce Guide](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=editing_picklists_for_record_types_and_business_processes.htm).

Comment: Ohh Wow. I just did not think about that. Thanks for reminding.